# Core Data debugging

Tags: ios, debugging, core-data, crash, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I developed an app and I am using Core Data. I used multiple MOC in the app and now it started crashing because some objects are modified in different contexts. The thing is that I can't see where and why?

If I use Xcode's exception breakpoint it stops where I create a child context and perform a block to create and save data. Before this worked, so I assume that something broke this what I introduced recently.

How should I start debugging this kind of problem?

Thank you very much for your answers.

**EDIT**

I realized that the bug was working with objects from different contexts and threads (Thanks to  LyricalPanda). Now I moved all the Core Data handling to [a MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)

While for debugging this was really helpful: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/

Comment: Are you accessing the different contexts on different threads simultaneously? Or is everything in the main thread?

Comment: Yes, they may be accessed simultaneously, since I don't want to do anything on the main thread. Should I create a context for every background access? Or how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the bug was working with objects from different contexts and threads (Thanks to  LyricalPanda). Now I moved all the Core Data handling to [a MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)

While for debugging this was really helpful: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/

– krisztian